# Which files are taking most of my process's I/O time?

Tags: python, linux, profiling

I have a fairly large python program that is causing a lot of disk I/O (on `top`, `%wa` can get as high as 80, and `iotop` says that my process is the culprit).

There are several things that may cause this - I'm writing to more than one log file, and I'm saving cached results to disk in several places, so it's not immediately obvious where I should focus my attention.

Is there a linux tool or a python trick that will allow me to see which subsystem is causing the most I/O operations?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#ProfilingCode

Comment: When you ran the profiler, what did you learn?

Comment: You could look in procfs to get a bird's eye view of what files the program is using: ls -la /proc/<pid>/fd

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at SystemTap. It's very powerful tracing and profiling mechanism for Linux system calls:
http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki

I'm sure it is possible to trace exactly which file descriptor is responsible for IO load - but it will get complicated to start with systemtap.